# Reduced Residue System Proof

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, reduced-residue-system

> Prove that if
>   $$r_1,r_2,...,r_{\phi(m)}$$
>   is a reduced residue system modulo $m$, and $m$ is odd, then
>   $$m|r_1+r_2+...+r_{\phi(m)}$$

My attempt at proof was to first prove that for any two natural numbers $a,b$, if $GCD(a,b)=1$, then $GCD(a-b,b)=1$. I then used this to state that if some $r_i$ is part of the reduced residue system, $m-r_i$ must be as well, so each $r_i$ in the sum can be paired with $m-r_i$ and the sum telescopes to $m+m+...+m$.

Is this correct? If so, what is the role of "and $m$ is odd" in the question?

Comment: In case $m=2$??

Comment: Are there any other even examples? I can see why $2$ would not work... in its case, there is only one positive integer less than it.

Comment: I think $2$ is the only exception,  but after a glass of wine, I’m not ready to state this categorically.

Comment: If $m$ is even, then there is the question of whether one of the $r_i$'s can be $m/2$. That's the only case in which you wouldn't be able to pair up one of the $r_i$'s. But in fact, since $m/2$ and $m$ are never relatively prime if $m > 2$ is even, the case $m = 2$ is the only exception. Probably, you also mean $\gcd(m, m-b) = \gcd(m,b)$.